# Replacing Wordpress comment_form

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to replace the comment_form with custom built solution. But I cannot seem to figure out how to do this and the code is lacking:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Ideally, anytime that the comment_form function is called, I want to replace it with an iframe to another site. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: create a file called comments.php

Comment: I'm building this as a plugin, not in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way you can overwrite comment_form() function,

if you want to overwrite comment_form then its not possible in right way.

instead you can you use filter like `comment_form_before` and `comment_form_after` to achieve what you want.

i am putting this answers because i just see code of comment_form()

something like

```
<?php add_action('comment_form_before',function(){
          echo '<div style="display:none;">';
      });

      add_action('comment_form_after',function(){
          echo '</div><iframe><iframe>';
      });
?>
```

Comment: Right, but the comment form still shows. I'm trying to get rid of the built in one entirely.

Comment: Tried, Ihave to what a few minutes before I can accept answer